# How to update checkboxes state based on an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the following code. Why am I not able to update the chekbox states based on `selected` array?

```js
var selected = [134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144];
$.each(selected, function(index, value){
  $("input[type='checkbox'][value"+ value.member_key+ "]").prop("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="133">133<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="134">134<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="135">135<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="136">136<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="137">137<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="138">138<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="139">139<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="140">140<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="141">141<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="142">142<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="143">143<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="144">144<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="145">145<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="146">146<br>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a `value.member_key`.  Your value is going to be just each number in the array...  Edit: also you are missing the `=` on your value selector matcher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no property named `member_key` on the passed `value`. Since you are implementing `.each()` on a number array, in each iteration the callback function will take the number itself as the second parameter. Hence, simply use `value`:

```js
var selected = [134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144];
 $.each(selected, function(index, value){
  $("input[type='checkbox'][value="+value+"]").prop("checked", true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="133">133<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="134">134<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="135">135<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="136">136<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="137">137<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="138">138<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="139">139<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="140">140<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="141">141<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="142">142<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="143">143<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="144">144<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="145">145<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="146">146<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var selected = [134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144];
 $.each(selected, function(index, value){
                                       //include the = and fix the value being compared
              $("input[type='checkbox'][value="+ value+ "]").prop("checked", true);
         })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="133">133<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="134">134<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="135">135<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="136">136<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="137">137<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="138">138<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="139">139<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="140">140<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="141">141<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="142">142<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="143">143<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="144">144<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="145">145<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="146">146<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are commenting on

```
value.member_key
```

I'd assume this is an error from copying the code to stackoverflow. I would guess the part you are missing in your actual code is the equals sign between the word "value" and its actual value.

your code will produce

```
[value133]
```

whereas you need

```
[value=133]
```